# How to track earnings made by my CSE (Google Custom Search)

Tags: adsense

Google offers a Custom Search engine, where i can provide a web Search through Google on my site (not a search on my Site rather on the whole Web)

https://cse.google.com/cse

Inside there, Ads of google AdSense will be displayed in the Search, same as in google.

How can i track if a user click one of the Ads and also the resulting earnings?

I want to determine if a user generate a rewerd an if yes, how much (money value).

How can i achiev this?

Edit:

So, i'm searching a lot and i've can't find any answer to this specific question out there.
There are some Docs for this on the Google Support site. They explain how to connect  CSE (Google Custom Search) with the required AdSense Account. They also write:

"..you might want to be able to track earnings made through searches on your site."

https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4514327?hl=en

Yes, thats exactly what are im trying to achieve, but the referral link in the Doc are unusable because they didnt realy explain it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried googling for Google's help on this? Also, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @RolfBly, thx for you suggestions

Comment: What you ask is very broad. That makes it hard to answer here. The link in your edit leads to [this one](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/65083?ctx=as2&rd=1). I'd recommend you read through that, digest it, determine your goal, and then try to follow the instructions.